# How to restart network services on Sierra?

Tags: network, macos

On FreeBSD/Linux, it is possible to restart network services by restarting a daemon.

Is there something similar in macOS Sierra?

Answer (score 24):

You can tear down and start up the network interface using:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 down
sudo ifconfig en0 up
```

Answer (score 13):

Network interfaces can also be Disabled & Enabled in System Preferences‑Network.

[image: Make Service Inactive]

Comment: If you've got some extra bridge and filter interfaces along with your main network service, make them inactive as well.

Answer (score 12):

The restarts Wi-Fi without `sudo`. Does anyone know how to do this with a *single command*?

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Comment: Create a shell script with those two lines, or use Automator to create an application from a shell script with those two lines. I just did the latter, seems to work fine.

Comment: You can perhaps use `&&` like so: `networksetup -setairportpower en0 off && networksetup -setairportpower en0 on` for single command.